# Why isn't my React Form sending?

Tags: reactjs, contact-form

I've used this tutorial offline and I have this:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../Normalize.css';
import '../App.css';
import $ from 'jquery';

class ReactFormLabel extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
render() {
    return(
     <label htmlFor={this.props.htmlFor}>{this.props.title}</label>
    )
  }
}

class ReactForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    subject: '',
    message: ''
  }
}

handleChange = (e) => {
  let newState = {};
  newState[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  this.setState(newState);
};

handleSubmit = (e, message) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let formData = {
    formSender: this.state.name,
    formEmail: this.state.email,
    formSubject: this.state.subject,
    formMessage: this.state.message
  }

  if (formData.formSender.length < 1 || formData.formEmail.length < 1 || formData.formSubject.length < 1 || formData.formMessage.length < 1) {
  return false;
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: '/some/url',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
    if (window.confirm('Thank you for your message. Can I erase the form?')) 
{
 document.querySelector('.form-input').val('');
}
},
error: function(xhr, status, err) {
  console.error(status, err.toString());
  alert('There was some problem with sending your message.');
 }
});

this.setState({
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: '',
  subject: '',
  message: ''
});
};

render() {
  return(
    <form className='react-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <fieldset className='form-group'>
        <ReactFormLabel htmlFor='formName' title='Full Name:' />
        <input id='formName' className='form-input' name='name' type='text' required onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.name} />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset className='form-group'>
        <ReactFormLabel htmlFor='formEmail' title='Email:' />
        <input id='formEmail' className='form-input' name='email' type='email' required onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email} />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset className='form-group'>
        <ReactFormLabel htmlFor='formSubject' title='Subject:'/>
        <input id='formSubject' className='form-input' name='subject' type='text' required onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.subject} />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset className='form-group'>
        <ReactFormLabel htmlFor='formMessage' title='Message:' />
        <textarea id='formMessage' className='form-textarea' name='message' required onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
      </fieldset>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <input id='formButton' className='btn' type='submit' placeholder='Send message' />
      </div>
    </form>
    )
  }
 };

export default ReactForm;
```

I think it has something to do with this section:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some/url',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
    if (window.confirm('Thank you for your message. Can I erase the form?')) 
{
 document.querySelector('.form-input').val('');
}
```

With the URL but I'm not too sure where to send it to? Is there something very simple I am overlooking here? It renders fine, it validates fine, it's just not sending. I followed this tutorial: https://blog.alexdevero.com/insanely-easy-simple-react-form-tutorial/

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: It's just not sending, what do I need to change to make it send the message successfully to an email account?

Comment: I am getting this error but's yellow in the console so this wouldn't stop it? 

webpackHotDevClient.js:239 ./src/Components/ReactForm.js
  Line 8:  Useless constructor  no-useless-constructor

Comment: your state is wrong, you've gotten one name and state has first/last name. emptying form via jquery is wrong - they are bound to your state via value (controlled) so you just need the `document.querySelector(".form-input").val("")` replaced with the empty state (which you do anyway). aside from that seems fine and should work. if it refuses to send, `some/url` may be wrong port/domain and you probably have a CORS issue

Comment: I'm still new to this, could you show me the corrections you mention above in the code if possible that I need to update? Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must bind your functions to the component like so:

```
class ReactForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            subject: '',
            message: ''
        } 

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
```

Also, here are the react docs detailing forms:  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html